# Amplifying light with fluorophores

Tags: optics, laser, fluorescence

The fluorescein fluorescence spectrum shown below shows distinct excitation and emission peaks (with some overlap). If I were to "pre-charge" a fluorescein solution with a laser at wavelength lambda1, could I use the excited molecules to amplify a pre-existing beam at wavelength lambda2 (that's outside the absorption spectrum of fluorescein but in the emission spectrum) without having to cause population inversion in fluorescein? All the search results I have come up with end up eventually point to how lasers work (population inversion and optical cavity) but I am not interested in lasing.

[image: fluorescein spectrum]

Comment: Do you mean amplified spontaneous emission (ASE), as distinct from true lasing? Lasing without inversion (LWI) is apparently also a thing.

Comment: I am referring to using an excited fluorophore to amplify another incident photon. I was wondering if the condition to invert population might not be needed as lambda2 is not in excitation range of flurophore and therefore won't be absorbed by the fluorophore.

Comment: I know, but I suggest looking at the two things I gave the acronyms for.  Without population inversion, your idea is not a standard dye laser, but maybe ASE and/or LWI will give you a lead to apply to your idea.